# Show TabView elements in Touch Bar - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, catalyst, tabview, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm working on a Mac app (via Mac Catalyst), and I'm looking for a way to display TabView items in the Touch Bar as well...

I tried with the .touchBar modifier, with the targetEnvironment(macCatalyst) and also with #if os(macOS), but no luck...

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

let furl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "path")

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selected = 0
    @State private var isActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            NavigationView {
                HomeView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 0 ? "house.fill" : "house"))
                Text("Home")
            }.tag(0)
            NavigationView {
                CategoryView(dm: DownloadManager())
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 1 ? "text.justify" : "text.justify"))
                Text("Categorie")
            }.tag(1)
            NavigationView {
                GalleryView(dm: DownloadManager())
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 2 ? "photo.fill" : "photo"))
                Text("Galleria")
            }.tag(2)
            NavigationView {
                FavoritesView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 3 ? "star.fill" : "star"))
                Text("Preferiti")
            }.tag(3)
            NavigationView {
                InfoView()
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: (selected == 4 ? "info.circle.fill" : "info.circle"))
                Text("Informazioni")
            }.tag(4)
        }
        .accentColor(.white)
        .onAppear() {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 112.0/255.0, green: 90.0/255.0, blue: 143.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 112.0/255.0, green: 90.0/255.0, blue: 143.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The SwiftUI .touchBar modifier isn’t available in Mac Catalyst, only MacOS.